# Imagemagick - Center an object in a given picture

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a task to write a PHP script that makes objects in the center of their pictures, For example [image]  [image]

Some of the pictures are horizontally oriented and some are vertically oriented based on that and the size of the white space I have to Crop/Add white space to the original picture.

The first method I had is by detecting the borders of the object within the picture but some picture doesn't have clear white background e.g: [image]

This Picture has extra white space on the borders and has gray gradient as the background which makes it harder to detect the object's borders, So I tried to apply The [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) by Imagemagick

```
exec("convert 1.jpg -define convolve:scale='50%!' -bias 50%  -morphology Convolve Sobel -solarize 50% -level 50,0%  ssc1.jpg");
```

The result was ok

[image]

And Now I have to find the borders in the filtered image, And the question is

What's the best way to find the coordinates of the borders (the output should be X1,X2,Y1,Y2)?

I have read some similar problems like [this one](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14646) that converts the image to text and remove white (black in my case) pixels but I'm not sure what's the best approach to solve this (I'm newbie in Image Processing).

Comment: I think until you're able to get rid of the artifacts still residing in the background you wont be able to accurately find the borders easily.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have time today to do this in ImageMagick, but I did an experiment in Photoshop and it seems to work nicely - at least for your lady on a gradated background.

1. I took the image and duplicated its layer in Photoshop (Cmd+J).
2. I set the Blending Mode of the upper layer to `Hard Mix`
3. I did Image->Trim from the menu at top of screen.

There is a good explanation of how `Hard Mix` works [here](http://www.clearps.com/photoshop-forum/index.php/t/28150/) at the bottom of the page.

You could emulate the `Hard Mix` effect using ImageMagick's `fx` operator like this [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php)

Hope the approach helps.

[image]

Comment: How did you get on with your problem?